# problem definition not clear Longest common prefix

Tags: algorithm, prefix

Problem Statements:
In an interview I faced a coding challenge with this question which I could not figure out.

`Given a string s contains lowercase alphabet, find the length of the Longest common Prefix of all substrings in O(n)`

```
For example 
s = 'ababac' 
Then substrings are as follow: 
1: s(1, 6) = ababac 
2: s(2, 6) = babac 
3: s(3, 6) = abac 
4: s(4, 6) = bac 
5: s(5, 6) = ac 
6: s(6, 6) = c 

Now, The lengths of LCP of all substrings are as follow 

1: len(LCP(s(1, 6), s)) = 6 
2: len(LCP(s(2, 6), s)) = 0 
3: len(LCP(s(3, 6), s)) = 3 
4: len(LCP(s(4, 6), s)) = 0 
5: len(LCP(s(5, 6), s)) = 1 
6: len(LCP(s(6, 6), s)) = 0 

String contains only lowercase alphabates.
```

I found out some same question in this community but they are just problem statement the meaning could not define.
[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53574799/longest-common-prefix-length-of-all-substrings-and-a-string#)

One of the leetcode problem is also somewhat like that which I understand perfectly and code: [Longest common prefix](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/) But my question sounds like same but the main difference is all this type of question provide a array of string but in my question there is a single string and I have to find out longest common prefix from this string.

Can any one please explain me the problem properly what exactly this question looking for?

Comment: You have an array of `String`s: all substrings of `s`. By some observations, you can argue why you need only to consider Substrings of form `s(i, 6)` (and `i` in `[1, 6]`).

Comment: Peripherla question: how is your question `java`-related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the longest common substring between two strings.  In each case, one of those is `s`, the original string.  The other string is a right-end substring of `s`.  These are the first list.

A few examples:

```
substring         common   len   reason
s(1, 6) = ababac  ababac    6     Comparing the string with itself yields the entire string
s(3, 6) = abac    aba       3     Only the first 3 characters match
s(4, 6) = bac     -none-    0     The first characters differ, so there is no common prefix.
```

Does that help?